# How do I call an Cosmos DB stored procedure from Azure Function in Python?

Tags: python, azure, stored-procedures, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an HTTP triggered Azure Function written in Python. I also have a CosmosDB container with a stored procedure which takes no parameters. How do I call this stored procedure from within the Azure Function's Python code?

- After reviewing the Cosmos docs, I know that one can create an HTTP trigger for the Cosmos DB send a request to the appropriate URL, but I've been unable to find out if this is necessary, and if it is, are there any Azure Python modules that create the necessary URLs and boiler plate.
- I've been unable to find in the Azure Functions docs if there are bindings for stored procedures.

```
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # What do I type here?
    return func.HttpResponse(....)
```

Comment: Have you seen this documentation already? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#stored-procedures---python-sdk. And there is no output bindings to trigger Cosmos DB stored procedures.

Comment: I have not seen that documentation. Let me take a look.

Comment: That looks like what I needed, but I won't have time to implement anything until this weekend.

Comment: This seems to work. Please type this up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Added as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the official python documentation on how to call a stored procedure [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#stored-procedures---python-sdk).

Also, there is no output bindings to trigger Cosmos DB stored procedures.

Comment: For newbies, such as myself, many other examples can be found on the [Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cosmos/)